# if $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable almost everywhere and right-continuous almost everywhere, is it absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-continuity

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined everywhere and differentiable almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. Moreover, the derivative $f'$ is integrable.

Assume further that $f$ is right-continuous almost everywhere. That is, there exists $E \subset [0,1)$ of measure zero such that if $t \in [0,1)-E$, then
\begin{equation}
f(t+\epsilon) \to f(t) \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0^+
\end{equation}

Then, I wonder if these conditions are sufficient to conclude that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Take $f$ defined at $1$ for $x\in[1/2,1]$ and $0$ for $x\in[0,1/2)$.

Comment: Oh....thank you for your insight...

Comment: So removing the “almost” won’t help. Don’t you need to assume continuity?

Comment: Even assuming continuity won't be enough - consider the "devil's staircase" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), with derivative $0$ a.e.